# Android instrumented test failed to instantiate test runner when using assertFailsWith from kotlin.test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing

I want to use `assertFailsWith` in an instrumented test to verify that a function fails with a certain exception.
However, when I add the dependency and use `assertFailsWith` in a test case, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate test runner class androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner
```

Test case:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun test_float() = runBlocking {
        val testValue = Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextFloat()

        assertFailsWith<UnsupportedOperationException>("Float not implemented and failed accordingly") {
            doSomething(testValue)
        }
    }
```

The instrumented test dependencies are

```
    // Instrumented tests
    // Core library
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:$androidXTestVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:$androidXTestVersion"

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$testRunnerVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$testRulesVersion"

    // To use android test orchestrator
    androidTestUtil "androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.1"

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$testJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:$testJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:truth:$truthVersion"

    // Instrumentation unit tests (that will require a real device or emulator)
    androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$kotlinTestVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion"
```

Versions are latest stable versions.

What am I doing wrong?